# Attach existing EC2 instance to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to create an Elastic Beanstalk environment using an existing Amazon EC2 instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to use existing Amazon EC2 instance directly, but you can create a custom AMI of your existing EC2 instances. And using the custom AMI to launch your EB environment.

You should also pay attention which AMI your existing EC2 instance used. If your existing EC2 instance is not using EB AMI, your EB environment will not run correctly. Because it lacks Host Manager.

References:

- [Create a Custom AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-create-custom-ami.html)
- [Using Custom AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html)